# If $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ is injective and $\lim a_n= a$, then $\lim a_{f(n)}= a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a convergent sequence with the limit $a$ and an injective function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $b_n = a_{f(n)}$. Prove that the sequence $\{b_n\}$ converges to $a$.

Any help for this exercise?
Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the readability of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;\epsilon>0\;$ , then there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ such that

$$n>N\implies |a_n-a|<\epsilon$$

Let now $\;K_N:=\left\{m\in\Bbb N\;|\; f(m)\le N\right\}\;$ . Since $\;f\;$ is injective, we get that $\;|K_N|\le N\;$ (why? Make this formal), so let $\;M\;$ be the maximal element of $\;K_N\;$ . Well, now check what happens to $\;|b_n-a|\;$ , for *any* $\;n>M\;$ ...